# Allow Google access to chat event export

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

When I tried to add https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/schedule/export/285/all to Google Calendar (Other Calendars -> Add by URL) it didn't have any events. Eventually, Google gave me an error message:

```
Could not fetch the url because robots.txt prevents us from crawling the url.
```

Indeed, checking https://chat.stackexchange.com/robots.txt the export URL is disallowed. It shouldn't be. It'd be really convenient to get room events on Google calendar automatically, without having to add each one.

Comment: Hmmm... I'm kinda surprised they ran robots.txt on that; but yes, it makes sense for that URL to be importable! will look in the AM (I have other changes in the "pipe" for chat, and I don't want to push it out at 11pm, in case it goes sour...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As soon as google slurp down the updated `robots.txt`, this should work. I have validated the change in webmaster-tools, with the verdict:

> Allowed (blah blah blah)